# Computing curvature with just the speed function

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose a curve $\vec{\gamma}:I \to \mathbb{R}^n$ have a smooth velocity function $\vec{v}$. Define $g(t)=\vec{v}(t)\cdot\vec{v}(t)$ (which is just speed squared). Suppose we do not have access to $\vec{\gamma}$ or any of its derivatives but instead we have access to $g$ and all of its derivatives. By "access" I mean the ability to compute the output of a function given some input.

By definition, the curvature of $\vec{\gamma}$ is defined as

$$\kappa(t)=\frac{|\vec{a}^\perp(t)|}{|\vec{v}(t)|^2}.$$

Is it possible to express the curvature of $\vec{\gamma}$ in terms of only $g$ and its derivatives?

Comment: Another way of asking the question seems to be "If we know the speed, can we determine the acceleration?". But the answer to the is no. Uniform circular motion has constant speed but non-zero acceleration (and curvature). Uniform linear motion has constant speed but zero acceleration and zero curvature.

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe Thanks! That's a great way of thinking about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situation is acutally even worse than stated in the comment of @JamieRadcliffe : Whenever you have a regularly paramtrized curve (i.e. one for which $g(t)\neq 0$ for all $t$), you can reparametrize it by arclength, i.e. in such a way that $g(t)\equiv 1$. Thus the function $g$ contains absolutely no information about the shape of the curve.